# Can we create cylindrical panorama from a polar panorama

Tags: photography

I have been trying to search a way out to convert polar panorama to cylindrical panorama. But I couldn't get anything on it.

So, I would like to ask if is it possible to do so?

Thanks

Comment: Or
Can we create a Virtual tour from a polar Panorama without converting it to cylindrical form?

Comment: You'll have to explain more of what you mean by a virtual tour

Answer (score 1):

Technically, there is a technique to convert a polar panorama to a cylindrical panorama, but the results won't be what you are looking for. The reason for this is that in the process of creating a polar panorama there is information lost because pixel data is changed.

So when I convert back to a rectangular/cylindrical form there will be blur damage all over, but mainly to the bottom and top of the image.

This is the result of the process:
[image]
[image: Backwards transformation]

As you can see, there is damage all over the image because of the process of creating a polar panorama. It is even more apparent when you zoom in.

If you want to try this process yourself. Use **Filter -> Distort -> Polar Coordinates** and choose the *polar to rectangular* option. After the transformation, you might have to vertically transform your image so the proportions are correct.